# Inline text - background color with padding

Tags: html, css

I need to make a Headline with background color which is not a block(only the text-bg is colored).

Here is an image of what I have to archieve:
[image]

And here is what I've got so far:
http://jsbin.com/tiwuquze/1/edit

You can see the padding is not right and I couldn't figure how to set it.
When you play around with the padding, you will see that it will overlap and the second line is not going in like the first one.

I am happy about every hint!

**Solution:**

John Smith made a working example: http://jsbin.com/tiwuquze/21/edit
He used `box-shadow` to emulate the left padding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UPDATE got the solution, use box shadow :D

```
h1 {
    background-color: #FE8020;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display:inline;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    line-height : 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left:0px;
    box-shadow: -16px 0 0 #FE8020; /* box shadow is emulating padding liek a charme */

}
```

for me this looks good

http://jsbin.com/tiwuquze/21/edit

Comment: no it doesnt, removing display inline makes it a block again

Comment: but sure the problem is the display inline

Comment: The background is not supposed to be on the whole block, just the text. Otherwise it would work like that, yes.

Comment: When I add your css to the js-bin, its a block again. Do you mind editing my example?

Comment: great! That works like a charm. Good idea to use box-shadow! I had to add padding-left to the container to align it to the other elements again but beside thats, its a good solution!

Comment: You can get arrround this by wrapping the h1 with a div and the div then has the padding to the left

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays (understanding years have passed since this question was posted), if you were willing to use [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental) and concerned primarily with modern browsers (and could accept how it looked without it on unsupported browsers), you could use [box-decoration-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break).

> The box-decoration-break CSS property specifies how an element's fragments should be rendered when broken across multiple lines, columns, or pages.

```
h1 {
    background-color: #FE8020;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display:inline;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    line-height : 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;padding-left:0px;box-shadow: -16px 0 0 #FE8020;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/hadedulici/1/edit

Also, for what it's worth, `box-shadow`-based solutions don't seem to work for me in Firefox 55.0.3 (Windows 7) nor Firefox Quantum 62.0.3 (Windows 10) at time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

To further `Brandon`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52843319/10282058), `box-decoration-break` is no longer flagged as experimental by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break), and is supported by 97.75% of browsers **for inline elements** according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-boxdecorationbreak) (2023-10-11)

For webkit based browsers (Chrome and many others), the webkit browser prefix must be added, i.e. `-webkit-box-decoration-break`

This property quite specifically addresses the original situation, handling even e.g. rounded corners, and is therefore the most accurate, current solution:

> The box-decoration-break CSS property specifies how an element's fragments should be rendered when broken across multiple lines, columns, or pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a bigger padding and use line-height 
example :

```
line-height:24px;
padding:4px;
```

Comment: It doesn't padding left and right if words wrap

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @ReKnawn suggested increase the padding and line-height just ensure that the line height is larger than the font-size + padding x 2 since in this case both the top and bottom are padded. eg if the font-size is 16 and padding is 4px line-height must be greater than 24 to ensure reasonable space and avoid overlapping

Answer (score -1):

here check this solution:

http://jsbin.com/tiwuquze/17/edit

Add a span inside the h1 element.

Comment: This makes it a block :(